# "Syntax error" in lambda function but tabbed properly and working in test case?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that is utilized to grab a user uploaded file via a react webapp, submit it to an s3 bucket, then a lambda function using python that grabs said image from the bucket, translates it, and submits a translated version of that file back into the bucket.

The issue is, this program is only working on the test cases/in theory. To extrapolate, I bring in the file name as the "event" for the lambda function, and carry it to various other functions like so:

```
def get_kv_map(event): 
    filePath = event
    fileExt = filePath.get('body')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('myBucket')
    obj = bucket.Object(bucket)
    client = boto3.client('textract') #We utilize boto3's textract
    response = client.analyze_document(Document={'S3Object': {'Bucket': 'myBucket', 'Name': fileExt}}, FeatureTypes=['FORMS'])
# Get the text blocks
    blocks=response['Blocks']     #We make a blocks variable that will be the blocks we find in the document
# get key and value maps
    key_map = {}
    value_map = {}
    block_map = {}
    for block in blocks:        #Traverse the blocks found in the document
        block_id = block['Id']          #Set variable for blockId to the Id's found on that block location
        block_map[block_id] = block                 #Make the block map at that ID be the block variable
        if block['BlockType'] == "KEY_VALUE_SET":       #if we see that the type of block we're on is a key and value set pair, we check if it's a key or not. If it's not a key, we know it's a value. We send it to the respective map. 
            if 'KEY' in block['EntityTypes']:
                key_map[block_id] = block
            else:
                value_map[block_id] = block
    return key_map, value_map, block_map                    #######LINE WITH ERROR ######
```

Why is this line the one causing an error, and more importantly, why is it only happening on the website? When I use the program in  cloud9 with my test cases, everything is perfectly fine. But the moment I try and have the website submit the data for the function to "do its work" it seems like it halts right after it uploads the file and gets to this line of all lines. I've tried checking tabs/spaces and everything. I'm very perplexed.

Thank you for any help, I've been pulling my hair out today.

So, I tried to analyze what I'm bringing (event) and what it contains. It seems that it's a permission error, but I cannot understand why. I gave myself full access to various features in AWS. Below is the error code I get when I utilize the test case as my event I see being brought in.

```
"errorType": "InvalidS3ObjectException",
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the AnalyzeDocument operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.",
"stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/scrapeShow/lambda_function.py\", line 133, in main\n    key_map, value_map, block_map = get_kv_map(event)   #Take map variables in to get the key and value map we need.\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/scrapeShow/lambda_function.py\", line 39, in get_kv_map\n    response = client.analyze_document(Document={'S3Object': {'Bucket': 'myBucket', 'Name': fileExt}}, FeatureTypes=['FORMS'])\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 316, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 626, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
]}
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: put code with correct indentations

Comment: All I get from the cloudwatch logs is this Syntax error in module func/lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 55)

Comment: Not sure why it's not indented properly, as it is on my IDE. I'll try and fix.

Comment: Are you sure the syntax error is in the `return key_map, value_map, block_map`? Because this is correct and is valid python code.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly where the error is pointed to, and precisely why it's confusing me.

Comment: please share the exact error.

Comment: @balderman the error seems to change at random. I've done nothing to the code since last night, started today and it's updated with the current error

Comment: That's not a syntax error. You have a problem with the call to `client.analyze_document`, though whether the issue is with the arguments or some sort of authentication error, I don't know.

Comment: You need to focus around analyze document.